# How to change price at run time in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have two text boxes. One for `itemNo` and a second for `quantity`.

In the `quantity` textbox, I have used `keypressed` event with enter key.

When I press enter on quantity, the `datagridview` fetches values from the dgv and shows them in the list.

My question is how to change the price at run time?

I have tried but not succeeded.

This is used for fetching item prices from database and showing it in a datagridview.

```
//here it is
public void enterToGrid()
{
    try
    {
        receipt obj = new receipt();
        bool found = false;
        string txt = "select * from products where qty>='" + tb_qty.Text + "' and id='" + tb_ino.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(txt, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            int price = int.Parse(tb_qty.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
            totalprice = totalprice + price;
            int tPrice = price;
            int p = int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
            int iCode = int.Parse(tb_ino.Text.ToString());
            int q = int.Parse(tb_qty.Text.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("item Code: " + iCode.ToString() + " Name : " + r[2].ToString() + " price : " + p.ToString() + " qty : " + q.ToString());
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Check if the product Id exists with the same Price
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == tb_ino.Text)
                    {

                        row.Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(tb_qty.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value));
                        row.Cells[5].Value = (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value)).ToString();
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                {                       
                    receipt rr = new receipt() { id = dataGridView1.RowCount, itemCode = Convert.ToInt32(tb_ino.Text), name = r[1].ToString(), quantity = Convert.ToInt32(tb_qty.Text), price = Convert.ToInt32(r[4]), total = ((Convert.ToInt32(tb_qty.Text) * (Convert.ToInt32(r[4])))) };
                    receiptBindingSource.Add(rr);
                    receiptBindingSource.MoveLast();
                }
            }
        }

        lbl_ti.Text = " " + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + " ";
        lbl_total.Text = " " + totalprice + " ";
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Error from database");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You say that you have tried but you didn't succeed. Could you please share your effort and show us in which point you got stuck? Doing so it would be more helpful for the readers of your question to understand your problem and suggest any possible solution. Thanks

Comment: May I suggest that you read about [MCVE]. You need to focus on the specific problem area; so I daresay that the sql-server tag is probably misplaced since it doesn't relate to your problem, and you probably need a WinForms tag (but I'm just guessing).

Comment: To change the price, use one of the math operators or methods.

Comment: @Richardissimo yes bro,  misplaced that.

Comment: @Christos OK bro.  I will post in few minutes.

Comment: I don't know how to post code.  But somehow I have tried

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: You also should wrap your connection and command objects in a USING statement. Much safer than trying to use try/catch and closing your connection. And of course this code will fail because you close the connection right before finally where it will close it again.

Comment: OK your question is reopened. Are you wanting to change the price in the database or when it is displayed? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: To add to SeanLange's points SqlDataReader is also disposable, so should be in a `using` block. I still have no idea what you need help with, though...

Comment: @SeanLange wanna change price not in database but in datagridview

Comment: @SeanLange I want to change price and quantity at run time but not in database.  Suppose if a known customer comes at your shop,  then you must give him discount. 

Same like that I want to do that

Comment: Ok that's great. Unless you can actually explain what something there is nothing here to answer. This would be a great place to start. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange I know I couldn't place question well. 
But let's try again. 

Question : 
How to change price and quantity entered to datagridview (fetched from db)  but changes only occur in datagridview  not in products table.

Comment: That depends. Do you want the user to enter the price? Or do you need to have some logic? You could do it in the query that populates the grid. This is just entirely too vague. I can't read your mind, I can't see your screen and I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I want users to enter price,  like if product price is 2000 $ and we may discount 100$ and give the same product at 1900$. I hope you get it